# ServiceStack - REST service does not deserialize json to request object

Tags: rest, servicestack

I have created a REST service in ServiceStack, but when I call it with the REST URL, it doesn't deserialize the JSON I post the service into my request object. If I use the default URL or supply the parameters in the query string it works fine.

My request object:

```
[Route("/myservice", "POST")]
public class MyRequestObject
{
    public string MyString { get; set; }
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
}
```

My Service:

```
public class MyService : Service
{
    public object Post(MyRequestObject request)
    {
        return new
            {
                MyString = request.MyString,
                MyInt = request.MyInt
            };
    }
}
```

And the json I post to the service:

```
{"myString": "abc", "myint": 42}
```

My REST URL is /api/myservice and the default URL is /api/json/asynconeway/MyRequestObject. I have verified that the service get's called with both the REST and default URL.

Thanks a bunch for your input.

## Success headers

### Request

```
POST /api/json/asynconeway/MyRequestObject HTTP/1.1
Host: bd.local
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 32
Origin: chrome-extension://aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: da-DK,da;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

### Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
COMMERCE-SERVER-SOFTWARE: Microsoft Commerce Server, Enterprise Edition
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/3,914 Win32NT/.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 01 Oct 2012 10:32:37 GMT
Content-Length: 29
```

## Error headers

### Request

```
POST /api/myservice HTTP/1.1
Host: bd.local
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 32
Origin: chrome-extension://aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: da-DK,da;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

### Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
COMMERCE-SERVER-SOFTWARE: Microsoft Commerce Server, Enterprise Edition
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/3,914 Win32NT/.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 01 Oct 2012 10:30:38 GMT
Content-Length: 11
```

Comment: You're not trying to make a GET request right? How are you POST'ing to it? does it work when you remove the "POST" verb?

Comment: No I am making a POST. I've tried via jQuery and Dev HTTP Client for Chrome - both works fine with the default URL. Does not work without the POST verb either.

Comment: It should work, but there's not enough information to determine the root cause. Ideally we'd want a stand-alone failing test at github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues - but if you supply your Request / Response HTTP Headers (success + failure) that might show the issue

Comment: Hi @mythz - I have added the header info to the question.

Comment: Note for the failed response, it looks like you just copy + pasted the HTTP request again? :)

Comment: Is there an answer to this?

Comment: No haven't found out yet (other than using the default urls).

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be in the code that makes the POST. Is the data json stringified, e.g.:

```
JSON.stringify({"myString": "abc", "myint": 42})
```