# ServiceStack JSON values null when using POST to custom Route

Tags: json, rest, servicestack

I'm pretty new to ServiceStack and REST services in general, so please excuse me if this is elementary or I'm going down the wrong path completely...

I'm using ServiceStack version 4.0.15, ORMLite, and SQL Server.

I am trying to set up a POST endpoint at a custom Route that accepts a JSON object in the message body and creates a record in the database from that object. The way I have it wired up right now, everything works fine if I POST to the default ServiceStack Route of [localhost]/json/reply/CreatePatientRequest. However, if I use my custom Route of [localhost]/patient, the request object has all null values when it gets to my Service.

First, I have a Patient DTO:

```
public class Patient
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int SSN { get; set; }
    ...
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my Request:

```
[Route("/patient", "POST")]
public class CreatePatientRequest : IReturn<PatientResponse>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int SSN { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

PatientResponse is just a class that returns the Id, First and Last names and a Message. All of these classes have additional properties as well. Here's my Service:

```
public class PatientService : Service
    {
        private static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApiDbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        private static OrmLiteConnectionFactory dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider);
        private static IDbConnection dbConn = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection();

        public PatientResponse Post(CreatePatientRequest request)
        {
            var response = new PatientResponse { Id = 0 };
            if (request.SSN == 0)
            {
                response.Message = "No SSN present in request. Please specify SSN and resend.";
                return response;
            }
            try
            {
                dbConn.Insert(new Patient
                {
                    FirstName = request.FirstName.ToString(),
                    LastName = request.LastName.ToString(),
                    SSN = request.SSN,
                    ...
                    CreatedAt = DateTime.Now
                });
                response.Message = "Record created successfully.";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response.Message = ex.Message;
            }

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Again, if I POST to the default ServiceStack Route for CreatePatientRequest, everything works great, the database gets updated, and I get the PatientResponse JSON returned. However, if I POST to my custom "/patient" Route, the CreatePatientRequest request object has all null values.

Someone please help! Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here's the Request Headers + body:

```
POST http://localhost:26809/patient HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:26809
Content-Length: 545

{
  "MDPatientId": "MD0003",
  "RXPatientId": "RX0003",
  "FirstName": "Sarah",
  "LastName": "Palin",
  "SSN": 135241234,
  "DateOfBirth": "\/Date(500274000000-0000)\/",
  "GenderId": 2,
  "RaceId": 1,
  "MaritalStatusId": 2,
  "PrimaryLanguageId": 1,
  "HomePhone": "",
  "CellPhone": "123-456-7890",
  "Email": "spalin@email.com",
  "Height": 58.000000,
  "Weight": 124.000000,
  "HIVStatus": "Negative",
  "Genotype": "1",
  "ViralLoad": "20,000,000",
  "DiagnosisCode": 183.740000
}
```

And the Response Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/4.015 Win32NT/.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcU291cmNlXFdvcmtzcGFjZXNcQ3VzdG9tQXV0aFxDdXN0b21BdXRoXHBhdGllbnQ=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 15 Apr 2014 16:11:27 GMT
Content-Length: 9252
```

The Response Body is a bunch of HTML that when viewed in Fiddler's WebView tab shows a "Snapshot of CreatePatientRequest generated by ServiceStack on ...", but there's no JSON response.

Comment: I had looked quite a bit before posting, but I just saw this similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670646/servicestack-rest-service-does-not-deserialize-json-to-request-object?rq=1. Just adding it as a reference here as they seem to be the same issue.

Comment: Can you provide the HTTP Headers for the request that fails? (you can use Chrome Web Inspector or Fiddler).

Comment: I mean the entire HTTP Request and Response headers (+ Request body), please add it to your question (i.e. not in comments).

Comment: @mythz, sorry about that...the OP has been updated with the information you requested. Thanks!

Comment: How are you making this request? There should be a `Content-Type: application/json` if sending JSON.

Comment: I'm using Fiddler's Composer, but get the same thing using Chrome's REST Console app. Adding the "Content-Type: application/json" header doesn't change anything. Also, note that if I POST to ServiceStack's default Route, everything works fine.

Comment: It works because the default route specifies json in the /pathinfo. All POST / PUT HTTP Requests need to specify a Content-Type of what they're sending. Can you update your post with the Request/Response headers after adding `Content-Type: application/json` (which should work). Also if you want a JSON response you should specify this with: `Accept: application/json`

Comment: @mythz...thank you! I did need both of those additional Headers. Now everything is working great. Please provide this as the answer so I can mark this post as complete. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making a raw JSON HTTP Request with a Request Body (e.g. POST/PUT) using a generic HTTP client like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), it's important to specify **what** you're sending using a `Content-Type: application/json` HTTP Header.

Also depending on what the Default ContentType of your service is, you should also specify what **response type** you want with `Accept: application/json`, e.g:

```
POST http://localhost:26809/patient HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Host: localhost:26809
Content-Length: xxx

{"json":"string"}
```

#### Setting the Default ContentType in ServiceStack

The Default ContentType in ServiceStack can be specified with:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
   DefaultContentType = MimeTypes.Json
});
```